# Using temporary table to compare 2 tables in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that compares 2 tables and makes them identical. I tried this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SESUS.Compare2Tables
      (@Table1 AS NVARCHAR(255),
       @Table2 AS NVARCHAR(255),
       @key AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmp

    --print 'SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM ' + @Table2  + ' except select * from ' + @Table1 + ';'
    --print 'delete from ' + @table1 + ' where ' + @key + ' in (select ' + @key + ' from #tmp);'  
    --print 'insert into ' +@table1 + ' select * from ' +@table2 + ' where ' +@key + ' in (select ' +@key + ' from #tmp);'

    exec ('SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM ' + @Table2  + ' except select * from ' + @Table1 + ';')
    exec ('delete from ' + @table1 + ' where ' + @key + ' in (select ' + @key + ' from #tmp)')
    exec ('insert into ' +@table1 + ' select * from ' +@table2 + ' where ' +@key + ' in (select ' +@key + ' from #tmp)')
END
```

But it returns the following error, any idea why it could insert into this temporary table, but cannot select form it?

> Invalid object name '#tmp'.

Comment: When I tried to use the same code without # for the temp table, it worked, however, I think this creates unneeded extra I/O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MERGE statement to sync with the second table.

```
MERGE table1 AS target
USING table2 AS source
ON source.id = target.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET col1 = source.col1, col2 = ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (id, col1, ...) VALUES (source.id, col1, ...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
;
```

Comment: Great Serge, SQL keeps surprising me :)
Regarding the insert, is there a way to dynamically retrieve a list of fields from both tables? I need this SP to be generic and accepts any couples of (identical design) tables.

Comment: Yes, you may retrieve columns from the `sys.columns` table joined with the `sys.tables` by `object_id`, and compose dynamic SQL statement. However, using of `sp_executesql` is highly recommended by vendor instead of `EXEC`

Comment: I have created a VERY GENERIC SP for this purpose, thank you for giving me the lead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148097/using-change-tracking-on-a-table-that-has-his-records-constantly-deleted-and-re

Answer (score 0):

try to execute all statements inside one execution because of the limited scope of temp tables:

```
exec ('SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM ' + @Table2  + ' except select * from ' + @Table1 + ';
        delete from ' + @table1 + ' where ' + @key + ' in (select ' + @key + ' from #tmp)
        insert into ' +@table1 + ' select * from ' +@table2 + ' where ' +@key + ' in (select ' +@key + ' from #tmp)')
```

You can also use global temp (`##tmp`) tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns null it fails to create temp table.

```
create Procedure SESUS.Compare2Tables(
    @Table1 as NVarchar(255),
    @Table2 as NVarchar(255),
    @key as NVarchar(max)
    )
AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmp') is not null
DROP TABLE #tmp

--print 'SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM ' + @Table2  + ' except select * from ' + @Table1 + ';'
--print 'delete from ' + @table1 + ' where ' + @key + ' in (select ' + @key + ' from #tmp);'
--print 'insert into ' +@table1 + ' select * from ' +@table2 + ' where ' +@key + ' in (select ' +@key + ' from #tmp);'

exec ('SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM ' + @Table2  + ' except select * from ' + @Table1 + ';')
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    exec ('delete from ' + @table1 + ' where ' + @key + ' in (select ' + @key + ' from #tmp)')
    exec ('insert into ' +@table1 + ' select * from ' +@table2 + ' where ' +@key + ' in (select ' +@key + ' from #tmp)')
End

END
```

Comment: You should **add an explanation** of what you've changed, and why that solves the problem the OP is seeing - don't just dump a pile of code without any comment!!

Comment: just check before executing the delete query is temp table really exist. if the first select statement returns null it will not generate #tem table.

Comment: @mark_s Sorry for that, it was the end of busy weekened, will consider in the future.
Thanks